# Efficient Algorithm to Find the n-th Odious Number

Tags: algorithms, number-theory, counting

An odious number is defined as an integer that has odd binary Hamming weight. I need an implementation of algorithm that finds the nth odious number, preferably recursive. Any ideas? A python script is also wanted, but I can write it myself once the algorithm is found.

More description can be found on formula section in OEIS: [A000069](https://oeis.org/A000069).

Comment: (Concentrate on `4k, 4k+1, 4k+2, 4k+3`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the recursive formula for odious numbers,
$$\begin{align}
a_1&=1,\\
a_{2n} &= 6n-3 -a_n,\\
a_{2n+1} &= a_{n+1} + 2n.
\end{align}$$
The formula can be proved easily by observing, as greybeard pointed out, there is exactly one odious number among $2k-1, 2k$ for all positive integer $k$.

Here is a simple algorithm in Python to compute the $n$-th odious number.

```python
def odious_number(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return 3 * (n - 1) - odious_number(n // 2)
    else:
        return odious_number((n + 1) // 2) + n - 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(1, 16):
        print(odious_number(i), end=", ")
    # Output: 1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14, 16, 19, 21, 22, 25, 26, 28,
```

---

There is also a "closed" formula.
$$a_n = 2n - 1 - \text{hamming_weight}(n - 1)\ \%\ 2$$

So, we have the following one-liner.

```python
def odious_number(n):
    return 2 * n - 1 - (n - 1).bit_count() % 2
```

<sub>`int.bit_count()`, which returns the Hamming weight of an integer, is available since Python 3.10. Before that version of Python, we can use, for example, `bin(i).count('1')`.</sub>

Comment: Yuval's answer shows how to prove the "closed" formula immediately. Be advised that he counts 1 as the 0-th odious number, while 1 is the first odious number in this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternative answer, following greybeard's advice. For each $k$, the two integers $2k,2k+1$ contain exactly one odious number. Hence the $i$th odious number is either $2i$ or $2i+1$: it is $2i$ if $i$ itself is odious, and $2i+1$ otherwise.

Stated differently, the $i$th odious number is $2i+1-b$, where $b$ is the parity of the number of ones in $i$.